# Visual Studio Code highlighting and clicking copy pastes

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, copy-paste, highlighting

When I highlight some text with my mouse and then click off of the highlighted text, sometimes it copy pastes that text right after what was highlighted. I don't want it to copy paste on click, I just want it to unhighlight. I looked through the settings and configurations of my VS code, and couldn't find a way to turn it off. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it thinks you are dragging and dropping the selection.  Does disabling   "editor.dragAndDrop": true,
to false help?

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks so much! That was so annoying.

Comment: Glad that helped, I'll make it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you mention sounds a lot like the copy, drag and drop functionality that vscode offers and I occasionally accidentally trigger.  It can be disabled by setting to false:

> // Controls if the editor should allow to move selections via drag and drop.
>
> "editor.dragAndDrop": false,